# How Do I Create Maps Like this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, games, maps

I'm working on a game project. I want to know how can I create such maps in photoshop. Notice how they look like. It looks as if you've handdrawn them, still looks very nice. Is there any way to create a same map in photoshop from scratch? I can only get solid rectangles instead of those cracks and turn ups.

Thank you!

[image: Map 2]

Comment: There are a lot more drawing tools than just the rectangle tool.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you can create this from scratch in Photoshop using various brushes but an easier way to do this is to draw it by hand on paper and then scan it in and open it up in photoshop to refine. Many designers use this technique as a starting point or just to get that organic feel for a piece.

Answer (score -1):

I believe your looking at an "Alpha channel", but it has been a while since I have been in Photoshop.  Alpha channels have many uses, look into it.

Comment: Hi! Can you expand a bit more on this and why you think the channels are the way to achieve this?